# Detecting multiaccouts with IP by username in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to find multiaccounts with MySQL query with 
`SELECT DISTINCT(ip) AS ip, name FROM {table} ORDER BY timestamp ASC;` 
and it lists all of them in fashion:

```
ip, name, timestamp

1, me, 2013-09-19 19:58:52
2, me, 2013-09-19 18:00:00
123, us, 2013-09-19 20:58:52
2, you, 2013-09-19 09:58:52
```

But how to select with logic:

1. find me all IPs of name = "me"
2. get all rows where IPs match point 1.
3. select all from point 2. but only 1 row for 1 ip-nick pair where
   it's timestam is latest

Pseudo query: 
`"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = "me" + ALL OTHER ROWS THAT MATCH "me" ip WHERE this row with IP must me the lastest timestamp;"`

to return:

```
1, me, 2013-09-19 19:58:52
2, you, 2013-09-19 09:58:52
```

If you know half on answer for ex. how to do it without latest timestamp I will welcome you answer too.

Comment: Shouldn't the second line of the desired result be `2, you`?

Comment: Correct - edited my qustion.

Answer (score 2):

Here's #2:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table t1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ip
      FROM Table
      WHERE name = "me") me_ip
ON t1.ip = me_ip.ip
```

Here's #3:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table t2
JOIN (SELECT t1.ip, t1.name, MAX(t1.timestamp) maxtime
      FROM Table t1
      JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ip
            FROM Table
            WHERE name = "me") me_ip
      ON t1.ip = me_ip.ip
      GROUP BY t1.ip, t1.name) t3
ON t2.ip = t3.ip AND t2.name = t3.name AND t2.timestamp = t3.maxtime
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show all matches, not just the latest.  So this does not satisfy point #3.  I will edit unless someone beats me to it.

```
SELECT  t1.*

FROM    table as t1

        JOIN (SELECT ip FROM table GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as dup
        ON t1.ip = dup.ip

ORDER BY t1.ip
```

Comment: Wow how this `t1.*` thing is called? Documentation summons me

Comment: `t1` a table alias, and `*` just means `all columns`.

Comment: Where did he say he only wants `COUNT(*) > 1`?

Comment: From the title, I assume he's looking for dups.

Comment: No, he said he wants to only show the row with the latest timestamp when there are dups.

Comment: It has a typo, the ip in the 2nd line should presumably be `2`.

Comment: I reread.  I think you're right.  I was trying to look for any ips with dupes.